# Java inheritance field set by parent class accessed by inner descendant

Tags: java, inheritance, java-7

I have a class diagram like this:

[image: diagram]

There is a parent abstract class called `BaseParent` with an inner static class `InnerStatic`. Two classes are extending it and it's inner class - `Foo` and `Bar` (this is always the case).

What I want is to have a field set for the base object

```
BaseParent parent = new Foo();
parent.setField(Field a);
```

Then inside the definition of `FooInner` and `BarInner`, I want to access that field that I previously set by calling `setField();`

```
public abstract class BaseParent{

public void setField();

public static class InnerStatic {

  }

}

public class Foo extends BaseParent{
    public static class FooInner extends InnerStatic{
         public void dummyMethod(){
            // access field here
         }
    }
}

public class Bar extends BaseParent{
    public static class BarInner extends InnerStatic{

    }
}
```

I tried to make the `field` and `setField()` static but then as soon as Foo called `setField` Bar's `field` would be changed too because it was static and the same.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Mixing static and inheritance not possible same time.

Comment: Actually I don't get how you inherited from 2 classes at the same time.

Comment: `BaseParent parent = new BaseParent();` should give a compiler error because `BaseParent`is abstract.

Comment: In Java you don't have multi inheritance. You can resolve it by a composition.

Comment: @Amr see https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3938f802470fdb18f277

Answer (score 1):

If I get what you want to do correctly I think this should work inside FooInner:

```
 Foo.this.getField();
```

This will give you a hold of the outer class object from the inner class object. Then When you get hold of class Foo you can now call it's super implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Brutally said, not. `Field` is owned by class `BaseParent`, and therefore `Foo` and `Bar` are both using the same `Field`.

A workaround you could consider, if you REALLY want to do it this way, is using a `static HashMap<Class,InnerStatic>`. The "normal" way to go would be to just let `Foo` and `Bar` have their own static InnerStatic.

Comment: They both are using only the same field if it is declared static, which OP already mentionned that he tried and knows it fails.

Comment: Which is why I supplied a workaround and added the "normal" way of doing it.